# Security of private key in server memory

Tags: encryption

Suppose I have a server that generates a private key in memory upon starting.

Is there anyway for a snooping administrator (say from Heroku or Nodejitsu) to recover that private key while that server instance is running (i.e. somehow access it within memory)?

If it matters, I'm running this on Node.JS

Comment: I've tried to answer this (negatively, I'm afraid), but this should really not be asked on stackoverflow. Try http://security.stackexchange.com next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what systems do they use and if they have features to prevent that from happening. Otherwise I can say that administrators who have access to the host can get your private key in so many ways. For example they can freeze your instant and save its state which basically copies the memory to the hard-disk, then unfreeze it and that doesn't take long on fast systems. Also they can dump the memory of your instance since it is simply a running app under the hypervisor. These might not be easy to do but based on my experience in the security field I can say they are very possible.

However, I think you should store the encrypted version of your key in the memory. And only decrypt it when it is being used so the decrypted version is only stored temporarily in the CPU registers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't just generate a private key, you generate a key pair. Then you must make sure that the other party uses the *trusted* public key of that key pair (to verify signatures or encrypt data). If they just use *any* public key then they cannot be sure it does not belong to an attacker. So even if the admin does not get access the private key, they simply can replace the public key with one they generated. So you would have a huge opportunity for a man in the middle attack.

Key management is hard. You cannot simply replace it with some haphazard scheme. There are a lot of (security) disadvantages about generating a key pair on each run as well. In general, it is not such a good idea.